# How to delete windows local group(Not Active directory Group) using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried the following code.

```
  DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
  Console.WriteLine("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
  DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + "/SSRS1,group");
  entry.Children.Remove(group);
  group.CommitChanges();
```

Group is being deleted successfully, But I am getting below exception.
Please help.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The group name could not be found.

[image: Please find the exception screenshot here]

Comment: Try wrapping it with a `try catch` to see what the exact error is

Comment: I did it and I got to know the solution or the same. Anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is enough to delete windows local group

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
  Console.WriteLine("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
  DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + "/SSRS1,group");
  entry.Children.Remove(group);
```